# Local storage of structured data in Win8 Metro-style apps

Tags: database, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In a desktop .NET application, the standard option for implementing a *local* relational database is to use SQL Server Compact Edition, and then of course there is the possibility to use SQLite and other third-party engines.

What are the options available to a .NET Metro-style application? SQL CE seems to be unavailable - any replacement? In fact, the entire `System.Data` namespace seems to be gone - so no LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework, either?

What about HTML5 IndexedDB that seems to be available to Metro HTML/JS apps - can that be used from .NET somehow?

Comment: Windows.Storage namespace is it.  The SQL guys are always late, aren't they :)

Comment: @Hans This lets you deal directly with files, but I'm looking for something where I don't have to do manual lookups and such - preferably a relational or object-oriented DB, or at least a file-backed key-value map. I bet db4o guys will be there sooner rather than later, but until then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the [Extensible Storage Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269259%28v=EXCHG.10%29.aspx) Win32 API (aka "JET Blue") is still available in Metro apps. C++ ones can use it directly via `#include <esent.h>`. .NET apps would have to use P/Invoke. This does not give SQL or any other sort of high-level relational querying constructs, but it does provide for key lookup, transactions, multiple indices per table, and multi-field indices.

Comment: .NET apps can use ManagedEsent (http://managedesent.codeplex.com/) rather than P/Invoke, it's done a lot of the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear: SQL CE exists in Windows 8. It exists not only in Program Files but in Windows\System32 to seem even **more embedded** than before. Windows7 doesn't have sqlcecompact40.dll in system32 so this is definitely new. System.Data and System.Data.Linq both live in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.

You can add references to those dlls manually but getting the app to compile is hit or miss. It seems that if you first open your project and *do nothing*, you can add a reference to those dlls anywhere and compile the app. If you remove the dlls and try to add them back you're hit with a "A reference to '<4.5 framework directory>' could not be added. If by some chance you can't add them via Visual Studio you can easily just add the HintPath manually.

My app now compiles but I also ran into an issue where linking the AppX wasn't working correctly and it gave a cryptic "Payload cannot contain 2 of the same dll" type messages. Like it was trying to include both 32 bit (the one I linked) and 64bit at the last minute. It included DLLs I wasn't touching manually like System.Data.OracleClient or System.Transactions so it was definitely some artifact from the build process I've yet to see again.

The main issue I'm dealing with right now is how to generate a proper connection string since it won't initialize properly without one. SQL CE is likely still looking for hardcoded C:\ references so the ApplicationData samples may not work as desired. I may try to make SQL CE 4 databases in Win7, transfer to Win8 and simply reference them locally but I'm kind of in the same boat there too. **This | |** close!

Please feel free to comment regarding any issues you run into and I'm definitely down for some offline collaboration if anyone would like to pool resources. This is definitely a thick forest of beasts and going it alone is proving a lot more challenging.

Comment: Well looks like the connection string problem is bigger than I thought. I get this error message: Provider 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5' not installed. Since there is no app/web.config to game this into being even by including the relevant dlls, this may be a permanent stopping point. It makes me wonder though why SQL CE is even included unless *something* is accessing it somehow.

Comment: Just because the DLL is there in Win8 doesn't mean that you can use it from within a Metro app. If it calls any Win32 API that is prohibited in a Metro app container (and there are many), it will not run. Even if it runs, it will still not pass the submission process for the Windows Store. Note that ESENT is _specifically_ whitelisted for app container!

Comment: Also, you cannot just drag in random assemblies from .NET 4.5 into your Metro app. It uses its own subset, .NET 4.5 Core, from which many assemblies are specifically excluded. The principle is the same - even if you manually add a reference to an assembly from full profile, it will either not work; or if it works, your app won't pass Windows Store approval.

Comment: You're correct, and I wasn't even thinking about this in the context of certification. I merely see SQL CE embedded in the operating system and due to its inclusion in things like WebMatrix jumped to a conclusion that this may become our preferred local storage medium. At least it seems to provide the least friction for most of us. SQL CE simply taunts me being embedded in the operating system for as it stands, apparently no reason?

Comment: Remember that Win8 is not only about Metro apps. You have to go Metro if you want to get into Windows Store, but in many areas a plain old desktop app makes more sense - and it has all existing frameworks accessible to it, including SQLCE and full .NET 4.5.