# Shopping cart app in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I would like to develop a small prototype on Windows 8 where I can select products and add them to cart. However I understand that WinRT does not support local databases (MS-Access, SQL), hence how can I store the product and cart information?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342511/local-database-storage-for-winrt-metro-applications

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite. See http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx for details.